# Get html of selector as string using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

Suppose I have an unordered list and I wanted to push the `html` of that list into an array, such that the output looked like the following:

```
arr = ["<li> item 1</li>", "<li> item 2 </li>", "<li> item 3 </li>"];
```

How might this be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get an array of Element objects then just `$('li').get()` will suffice.

If you want each `li` element as a string of HTML then you can use `map()` along with `outerHTML`, like this:

```js
var arr = $('li').map(function() {
  return this.outerHTML;
}).get();
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```